# Reduce response time

Tags: spring-boot, retrofit, rx-java2, apache-commons

The operation `api.getProducts(..)` with the help of Retrofit, we invoke a GET from another API. Now, `repeatUntil()` is used since the other API returns a page and there is a specific `documentId` that has more than 200 records, and for each invocation, for example, it only returns a page with 30 records, so 170 would be missing. records. So with `repeatUntil` I manage to get the 200 records and display them in a single invocation.

BUT, this happens to take about 7 seconds and I need to know if there is another way to do this without it being time consuming.

I use Spring Boot + RxJava

```
public TriFunction<Map<String, String>, String, ProductPending, Single<List<ProductSearch>>> getProducts() {


 return (headers, documentId, product) -> api.getProducts(headers, documentId, EXTRA_FIELDS)
  .map(response -> handleHeaderFromResponse().apply(product, response, headers))
  .repeatUntil(() -> !product.isItemsPending())
  .doOnNext( // evaluate miliseconds )
  .anotherOperator(..)
  .toList()
  .doOnSuccess(productsSearch ->
    log.debug(LOG_PREFIX + "Success PRODUCT-> getProduct -> documentId: {}",
        personId.replaceAll("[\r\n]", StringUtils.EMPTY))
  )
  .doOnError(ex -> log.error(LOG_PREFIX + "Error Product -> getProducts-> DocumentId: {}", documentId.replaceAll("[\r\n]", StringUtils.EMPTY)))
  .onErrorResumeNext(..)
  .subscribeOn(io());
}
```

Comment: best solution would be changing the `api.getProducts` to get paging size as parameter and request 200 element in one go. From rxjava side you can try to make those calls parrallel but this sounds like because of they dependent(documentId) to each other they have to wait the earlier call.